What does engage a solicitor mean?
What is the difference between engage a solicitor and hire a solicitor?
Engage primarily use its involvement meaning, like he engages the cooperation. Eo why does engage derive the meaning of hiring?

You might be better asking on Law SE if the details are important. When a solicitor undertakes to represent someone, they enter into a particular relationship where there are certain duties and responsibilities. If you want the precise legal terminology (for a given country/jurisdiction) you can ask there. For everyday English check the duplicate.

Because in English engage means hire too. Look it up in a dictionary. engage someone's services, for example. It isn't legal per se at all.

Solicitors mainly work in British English speaking countries. In those, you may hire a workman to dig a hole in your yard, or fix your pipes, but you engage a professional (e.g. a solicitor, accountant, etc). It's a status thing.
